# Don't want to wait \n while reading inputStream

Tags: java, newline, inputstream, telnet

I'm making a console game, where user connects via telnet to a server and has to press `spacebar` when sees a particular number. is it possible to make user press only `spacebar`, without submitting it by pressing `enter`?

Currently i'm using `BufferedReader` `read()` method, but if i have to use something else, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do on the server, you need to replace the client. The telnet client waits until the user presses Enter before sending a complete line of text to the server.